# How to copy files. iterating whitespace directories - batch

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, directory, whitespace

Hello i want to create a batch file that copies the files from the current directory to another.

```
for /F "usebackq" %%b IN (`DIR /B /S ""`) DO @(
   XCOPY %%b %1
)
```

So Far so good.

MY problem are the whitespaces in directories.

So when the name of a directory is /Dir whitespaces end/

it does not copy it.  "File not found - Dir"

Start bat file with destination

> CopyFiles.bat "I:\testFolder*.*"

How can i work around this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /b /s ') do xcopy "%%~b" "%1"
```

Important is 1) set `"delims="`  and  2) enclose for loop and other variables in double quotes.